# Parse error trying parameterize $_SESSION into query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i'm new on PDO.

I need to parameterize  $_SESSION['lang']

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE cat_parent_id=:parentid AND cat_lang = '{$_SESSION['lang']}'";

$stmt->execute(array( 'parentid' => $cat_parent_id));
```

So i tried in this way:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE cat_parent_id=:parentid AND cat_lang = :id";
$stmt->execute(array( 'parentid' => $cat_parent_id), 'id' => $_SESSION['lang']);
```

but i have an parse error on execute: *Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in....*

what's wrong? Thanks

Comment: You close the array before you start the id

Comment: ah ok, it works..i just don't understand why $_SESSION must be put inside the array, anyway thanks

Comment: You can use `[ ... ]` as an alternative to `array( ... )` in newer versions of PHP.